# Python Canvas object.coords inverted

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to programming and I've just written this little code to move a ball around in a canvas. It works quite well, excepted that the 'Top' and 'Bottom' buttons don't work as expected; they do exactly the opposite of what they're supposed to do ! 
I apologize but after an hour of headache I just can't get it. Thanks for your help.

```
from tkinter import *

x1, y1 = 135, 135

def moveo (lr, tb):
    global x1, y1
    x1, y1 = x1+lr, y1+tb
    can.coords (oval, x1, y1, x1+30, y1+30)

def moveLeft ():
    moveo (-10,0)

def moveRight ():
    moveo (10,0)

def moveTop ():
    moveo (0,10)

def moveBottom ():
    moveo (0,-10)


##########MAIN############

wind = Tk()
wind.title ("Move Da Ball")

can = Canvas (wind, width = 300, height = 300, bg = "light blue")
can.pack (side = LEFT,padx = 5, pady = 5)
oval = can.create_oval(x1,y1,x1+30,y1+30,width=2,fill='orange')
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=moveLeft).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Right', command=moveRight).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Top', command=moveTop).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Bottom', command=moveBottom).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Quit', command=wind.destroy).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)


wind.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin point (0, 0) is in the **top left** corner of the screen. As you go right, the x axis increases and as you go **down** the y axis increases.

[image]